# Where were you? vs Where did you go?

Tags: past-simple

Could you explain me if both questions are correct in this example?

*Did you enjoy your holiday? Yes thanks, it was wonderful.* 
And then ...

> 1. Where were you?
> 2. Where did you go?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct. The second sentence is a little more idiomatic, since it implies travel.